# How to output only file names (with spaces) in ls -Al?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

I should echo only names of files or directories with this construction:

```
ls -Al | while read string
do
...
done
```

`ls -Al` output :

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 s162103  studs         12 march 28 12:49 personal domain
drwxr-xr-x   2 s162103  studs          3 march 28 22:32 public_html
drwxr-xr-x   7 s162103  studs          8 march 28 13:59 WebApplication1
```

For example if I try:

```
ls -Al | while read string
do
echo "$string" | awk '{print $9}
done
```

then output only files and directories without spaces. If file or directory have spaces like "personal domain" it will be only word "personal".

I need very simple solution. Maybe there is better solution than awk.

Comment: Why not just `ls -Al *' '*`? Parsing `ls`'s output never leads to anything good.

Comment: If you need something that will work in any *nix try avoiding using `ls -Al | while`. A simple and more reliable way is `for string in *; do echo "$string"; done`.

Comment: need only with this construction..okay,not simple,any solution!

Comment: Why do you _need_ `ls`? Parsing `ls` and "work in all *nix and will not break if something happened" do not go well together.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you have a directory name `"personal domain"`, how is the substring `"personal"` useful? And if you want to filter out the additional information other than the name, why are you using the `-l` option?

Comment: You misspelled it :-) Try `A1`, not `Al`.

Comment: does not work if the filename has a space

Comment: find ./  -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n"

Answer (score 181):

You [really should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If this is a homework assignment and you are required to, your professor does not know what they're talking about. Why don't you do something like this:

### The good...

```
find ./  -printf "%f\n"
```

or

```
for n in *; do printf '%s\n' "$n"; done
```

### ...the bad...

If you *really really* want to use `ls`, you can make it a little bit more robust by doing something like this:

```
ls -lA | awk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}'
```

### ...and the ugly

If you *insist* on doing it the wrong, dangerous way and just have to use a `while` loop, do this:

```
ls -Al | while IFS= read -r string; do echo "$string" | 
    awk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}'; done
```

Seriously though, just don't.

Comment: `drwx------   2 s162103  studs          3 oct.  9  2012 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x   3 s162103  studs          6 oct. 25 09:02 .subversion
drwxrwxrwt   3 s162103  studs          3 nov. 15  2012 .TempoItems`
sometimes i've got date without time, only year and gawk return empty

Comment: @AlexZern Well, that's one of the reasons you don't parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: @AlexZern why do you need the `-l` switch anyway? If all you want is the file names, just run `ls -A`. Using `-l` just makes your life harder since you now have to parse the output.

Comment: because I need additional information like access, date, owner,etc.  And I wrote a huge script ,which works well, except print file and dir names with spaces.

Comment: OK then. What we have here is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). `ls` is just not the best way of getting what you need. Why don't you post a new question explaining the information you want to collect and we can suggest ways of doing it. Alternatively, you can use your script as is, and use one of the suggestions above to print the name only. But seriously, don't parse `ls`, just tell us exactly what you are trying to do in a new question.

Comment: `ls -lA | gawk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}'` is in no way robust (and does not require GNU `awk`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it is more robust than the OP's `while` loop. Of course it's not good, that's kind of the whole point of this answer. I removed the `echo`, again, that wasn't the point I was trying to make there but OK, may as well make it safer. As for `gawk`, fair enough. I just used it by default, I wasn't suggesting it was needed.

Comment: I used this to generate include "file.php" for 70 files in 1 folder... great answer

Comment: Taking a cue from the above - I have used the command:
`find -maxdepth 1 -name "abc*" -printf "%f\n"`

Answer (score 178):

Is there some reason that `ls -A1`* won't work?

E.g.:

```
$ touch file1 file2 file\ with\ spaces
$ ls -Al
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 bahamat bahamat 0 Mar 30 22:31 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bahamat bahamat 0 Mar 30 22:31 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 bahamat bahamat 0 Mar 30 22:31 file with spaces
$ ls -A1
file1
file2
file with spaces
$
```

---

* Note: that's a capital letter A and the number one.

Comment: TIL about `ls -A1` and I can see it being very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 109):

I wonder why no one mentioned this simple command:

```
ls -a | sort
```

Comment: Brilliant! Any idea how piping to `sort` causes multi-column block to be unpivoted into single column?

Comment: @msciwoj it just takes any strings separated by whitespaces and prints them sorted separated by endlines

Comment: It works here because `ls` reverts to `ls -1` (single columnd output) when its output doesn't go to a terminal (and disables non-printable character quoting/replacement; @Kusalananda, your `ls` is not POSIX compliant if it still does). `ls` output is already sorted. So piping it to `sort` will at best do nothing, and at worse mangle the output (if file names contain newline characters) or  fail for filenames that are not text. `ls -a | cat` would be better. Or even better `ls -A1` as already mentioned (and because you generally do want the replacements/quoting when displayed on a terminal)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Noted. `ls` behaves differently when output is not a terminal.

Comment: it's not the sort command that causes a single column, it's the `ls -a` which can be used by itself

Answer (score 8):

You cannot parse the output of `ls`, let alone `ls -l` because newline, just like space is as valid a character as any in a filename. Also, you'll need to consider symlinks that have an output like `... foo -> bar`.

Why would you use `-l` anyway if you only want the file name?

Just do:

```
for file in *; do
  ...
done
```

If you want to include dot files (except `.` and `..`), depending on the shell:

`zsh`:

```
for file in *(ND); do
  ...
done
```

`bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for file in *; do
  ...
done
```

`ksh93`:

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
for file in ~(N)*; do
  ...
done
```

POSIXly:

```
for file in .[!.]* ..?* *; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ] || continue
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
ls -lA | awk '{print $9}'
```

It will work if you happen not to have any files with spaces in
their names.... otherwise a slightly more convoluted approach
may work:

```
ls -lA | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""; print $0;}
```

Comment: The question does explicitly state "with spaces". Your second one adds whitespace at the start and squeezes sequences of blanks into one space character and won't work for symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for file in * .[!.]*
do
  printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Comment: That misses files named like `..whatever`.

Comment: True, good point. I just noticed your addition to cater for that in your later post above :+1 and it needs tests for existence indeed...

Answer (score 2):

Try (`bash`, `zsh` syntax):

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  ...
done
```

> This goes recursive and lists only on normal files (i.e. no dirs or symlinks/fifos/devices...).

See also:

- [List only regular files (but not directories) in current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48492/21471)
- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) at wooledge wiki
- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) at unix SE

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -Al | tr -s ' ' | cut -f9- -d' '
```

compress multiple spaces into single spaces with tr then you can use cut to split on the fields

Comment: In my case where I knew the full path just not the file name, `cut` worked best. Full command for getting the most recent with version-aware sorting: `ls /workdir/node-* | cut -f 3 -d / | sort -V -r | head -n 1`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to print all file names in directory is just:

```
echo *
```

Downside - won't print hidden files.

Comment: Depending on the shell, there may be shell options to set to make the pattern expand to hidden names (e.g. `dotglob` in the `bash` shell), or special patterns that does so (like `*(D)` in the `zsh` shell). This is mentioned in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195542/116858).

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this:

`ls -A | xargs -I% echo %`

Comment: But that doesn't work properly if there are filenames that contain apostrophes, double quotes, backslashes or newlines or start with blank characters.

Comment: @Dick the question is about `ls -Al`, with the `-l` option. If you’re going to use `ls -A`, there’s no need to post-process its output with `xargs` or anything else; `ls -A` already only outputs file names. If you want to have at most one file per line, use `ls -A1`, [as already mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70663/86440).