# How to retrieve folders name in a directory with bash

Tags: bash, directory, filenames

I'm trying to get the names of the folders inside another folder. I was trying to use the bellow code but the problem is that it return the full address of the folder instead of just the folder name

```
for folder in /[my folder]/*; do cat $folder;  done
```

With this I get `/[my folder]/subfolder1`, what I expected was just the `subfolder1`.

Thank you

Comment: `cat` is not meant for folders but text files...

Comment: Use ls instead cat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output only file names (with spaces) in ls -Al?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70614/how-to-output-only-file-names-with-spaces-in-ls-al)

Comment: @quasimodo Good catch but not what they were looking for. I got this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cat` is a program that simply takes its input stream, or a file, and prints it to standard output. You cannot `cat` a directory, that doesn't make sense. If you just want to see the names of all first level subdirectories of a given directory, you can use `echo` which simply prints what you give it:

```
$ for dir in foo/*/; do echo "$dir"; done
foo/dir1/
foo/dir2/
foo/dir3/
foo/dir4/
```

You don't even need a loop:

```
$ echo foo/*/
foo/dir1/ foo/dir2/ foo/dir3/ foo/dir4
```

To get only the directory names, without the path:

```
$ for dir in foo/*/; do basename "$dir"; done
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
```

Alternatively, you can `cd` to the path:

```
$ cd foo
$ echo */
dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ dir4/
```

Or `cd` in a subshell so you stay where you were originally when the command finishes:

```
$ ( cd foo && echo */ )
dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ dir4/
```

Or, to get them on separate lines and also to ensure that this will work even on weird directory names (e.g. a name that contains a newline):

```
    $ ( cd foo && printf -- '%s\n' */ ) 
    dir1/
    dir2/
    dir3/
    dir4/
```

Finally, if your directory names can contain newlines or other strangeness, use:

Comment: This was perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: `basename -- "$dir"`, with double dash, to avoid pitfalls.